# Virtualbox test pattern on ubuntu install

Tags: ubuntu, installation, virtualbox

[image]

I was able to install Centos 7 (64-bit) without a problem, but now installing Ubuntu 14.10 (64-bit) and all I get is this test pattern.

In VirtualBox I'm loading the iso to the cd-rom as per normal but as the install window progresses it turns into this.  Ubuntu starts off with the 14.10 dots and purple screen then this test pattern.  I tried upgrading VirtualBox and up'ing the display driver memory but still no luck.  Currently using 4.3.20.

HP Elitebook 8540w Nvidia graphics.  Any ideas why it would be so different than Centos 7?

Thanks

Comment: It's not a test pattern, it's a display driver bug.  Notice the distorted mouse cursor on the right.  Try a different display driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VirtualBox uses additional RAM beyond the normal amount of RAM used by your system. If the RAM in your graphics card is failing, sometimes just a small fraction of the RAM goes bad while the rest of the RAM continues to work properly.<sup>1</sup> This can result in a screen that has repeating patterns of visual artifacts like the screenshot in your question.

<sup>1</sup><sub>[PlayTool: Diagnose video card problems by comparing with example corrupted screens](http://www.playtool.com/pages/artifacts/artifacts.html)</sub>

Comment: Thanks.  Your comment lead me to the solution.  I'm using a extended monitor, and so I reverted back to the laptop screen, whereupon the install of Ubuntu started to work correctly with the Try Ubuntu / Install Ubuntu screen that I was not getting before.  Marked as correct as it lead me to think about the display driver and why it would be suddenly different.  I just had to revert to a more default state for the computer for the install.  Thus the video card is happier.  Thanks.

Comment: Confirmed, that worked.  

Conclusion: using an extended monitor on laptops can cause display artifacts on VirtualBox installations. Turning off the projector display to the regular laptop screen, removes the error.  I then installed Guest Additions, and proceeded to return to projector mode successfully.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Press right ctrl + F2 and then right ctrl + F1

Source:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/769589/16-04-live-cd-screen-resolution-problem